# Displaying an open Manipulator

Tags: manipulate

Take something like:

```
Manipulate[N[Pi]*s, {{s, 5}, 0, 10}]
```

This results in the following:

[image: The <code>+</code> sign has not been clicked]

What I would really like is the following:

[image: The <code>+</code> sign has been clicked]

Is there any way to make this happen by default?  In other words, is there a flag I can set so that the little `+` sign is clicked by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
Manipulate[N[Pi]*s, {{s, 5}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

The initial display of this expression when evaluated will be

[image: open manipulator]

To find this option in the Documentation Center, you need to be aware that the control you are using is a `Manipulator` and not a `Slider`.